Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.UpdateServices.BaseApi' with the referenced "Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll"
I'm developing an "ASP.Net Core Web API" in Framework .Net 8.0 working with Microsoft WSUS, I have referenced the file :
C:\Program Files\Update Services\Api\Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll

When I try to run the code :
AdminProxy proxy = new AdminProxy();

objUpdateServer = proxy.GetRemoteUpdateServerInstance(sServerName, false, iPort);

I get this exception at the 2nd line :

{"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.UpdateServices.BaseApi,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
The system cannot find the file
specified.":"Microsoft.UpdateServices.BaseApi, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName
assemblyName, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext
assemblyLoadContext, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, Boolean
throwOnFileNotFound)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
assemblyString)    at
Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.CreateUpdateServer(Object[]
args)    at
Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer(String
serverName, Boolean useSecureConnection, Int32 portNumber)    at
Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy.GetRemoteUpdateServerInstance(String
serverName, Boolean useSecureConnection, Int32 portNumber)    at
iWSUS_Server.WSUSAPI..ctor(String sServerName, Int32 iPort, Logger
pm_Logger) in
C:\GitLab\Projects\iWSUS-Server\iWSUS_Server\Classes\WSUSAPI.cs:line 32

How can I fix this problem ?
I had developed a WCF service in Framework 4.7.2 with the same referenced dll and this was working properly.
Thanks per advance for your help :)

Seems that BaseApi library is for 4.2.7 Framework and will no work on .Net8 app. Try to find this package in Nuget manager

Not available in the NuGet packages manager...

So, first option is not to use .Net8. The second is try to create a combined application, where some main part is .Net app and other is small 4.7.2 lib. But with the second approach you may face with same problems like you have now
